# Can't fetch rows from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm a bit rusty on mysql, especially now that it's mysql**i**... Nothing happens in the script below, the variables $row[username] etc are empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once('./db_config.php');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']));

$query = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";

if($res = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{
    $row = mysqli_num_rows($res);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['Join_Date'] = $row['join_date'];
    mysqli_free_result($res);

    header('Location: ../index.php');
} else
{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` returns the column count, not the row.

Comment: i think there is typo in your code, i can not find `mysqli_fetch_array` in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not fetching the records instead you are doing myql_num_rows(this will give only no of record)

use this to fetch records

> `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once('./db_config.php');

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']));

$query = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";

if($res = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
{

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_NUM);
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $row['username'];
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['Join_Date'] = $row['join_date'];
    mysqli_free_result($res);

    header('Location: ../index.php');
} else
{
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
}

?>
```

Comment: Good to notice that you have actually mentioned what was wrong and then your answer.

Comment: @Anish Thanks for the answer! It still gives me a bunch of undefinded index errors, for example: `Notice: Undefined index: username`

Comment: can you paste it here?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\wamp\www\gor\scripts\login.php on line 19` `Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\gor\scripts\login.php on line 20` `Notice: Undefined index: join_date in C:\wamp\www\gorgame\scripts\login.php on line 21`

Comment: ok. echo the $query on your browser ,then run it in the db directly and see whether it is return any results for that query.

Comment: The query is correct: `SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = 'Micard' AND password = 'admin'`
SQL Query is successful and returns 1 total row in phpmyadmin

Comment: It's still not fetching it properly I think. I'm the old mysql user, now I'm just trying to get my head around mysqli

Comment: hmmm. Is your script connecting to database ? . and where is the $con variable is getting set? Please check that as well.

Comment: It seems to be connecting, otherwise it would be spitting out an error right away. It's basically complaining about this part: `$_SESSION['Username'] = $row['username']` Doesn't like username in row array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120193/discussion-between-anish-and-micard).

Comment: Here's my conn: 
`$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}`

Comment: :). ok. then you please check the output of mysqli_fetch_array as well

Comment: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => Micard [2] => admin [3] => 2016-08-04 )

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured. I tried running it simply as $row[1] etc and it worked. I've changed to assoc, and working now the way I wanted :) Thank you!